# {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my `Web Api` I have two `controllers`  and each controller I have one `get method` and one `post method`. In get method it's working perfectly but in post method it's not working and throwing this error,

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

[This is my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCc9C.jpg)

Comment: I think you should put the code in the post (as as image).

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006454/795683

Comment: this is my routing for both method
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "Sales",
               routeTemplate: "api/{Sales}/{jsonresponce}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Sales", action = "Postsomething" }
            );



            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "User",
                  routeTemplate: "api/{User}/{GetDetails}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "GetDetails" }
               );

Comment: Your action method in Sales controller says "PostSomething" Have you put [HttpPost] attribute over it? And what are you trying to do with that method? If it's not getting anything from a source,then probably the error would come.

Comment: yes i have added the attribute.... error is coming in get method bhai....

Comment: can you show the code for both these methods?

Comment: you can check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005788/asp-net-web-api-the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-get. Hope it helps